# __pycache__ merge conflicts not resolved by gitignore

Tags: python, git

I am trying to merge a development branch back into the master. I have run `git rm '*.pyc'` in both files and this is my gitignore (copied from [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore)):

```
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

# C extensions
*.so

# Distribution / packaging
.Python
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
wheels/
share/python-wheels/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
MANIFEST

# PyInstaller
#  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
#  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.
*.manifest
*.spec

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
htmlcov/
.tox/
.nox/
.coverage
.coverage.*
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml
*.cover
*.py,cover
.hypothesis/
.pytest_cache/
cover/

# Translations
*.mo
*.pot

# Django stuff:
*.log
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
db.sqlite3-journal

# Flask stuff:
instance/
.webassets-cache

# Scrapy stuff:
.scrapy

# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/

# PyBuilder
.pybuilder/
target/

# Jupyter Notebook
.ipynb_checkpoints

# IPython
profile_default/
ipython_config.py

# pyenv
#   For a library or package, you might want to ignore these files since the code is
#   intended to run in multiple environments; otherwise, check them in:
# .python-version

# pipenv
#   According to pypa/pipenv#598, it is recommended to include Pipfile.lock in version control.
#   However, in case of collaboration, if having platform-specific dependencies or dependencies
#   having no cross-platform support, pipenv may install dependencies that don't work, or not
#   install all needed dependencies.
#Pipfile.lock

# PEP 582; used by e.g. github.com/David-OConnor/pyflow
__pypackages__/

# Celery stuff
celerybeat-schedule
celerybeat.pid

# SageMath parsed files
*.sage.py

# Environments
.env
.venv
env/
venv/
ENV/
env.bak/
venv.bak/

# Spyder project settings
.spyderproject
.spyproject

# Rope project settings
.ropeproject

# mkdocs documentation
/site

# mypy
.mypy_cache/
.dmypy.json
dmypy.json

# Pyre type checker
.pyre/

# pytype static type analyzer
.pytype/

# Cython debug symbols
cython_debug/
```

However, when I do

```
git checkout master
git merge version3ascii
```

(`version3ascii` is the name of my development branch)

I am getting the following error messages:

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_subprocess.cpython-37 2.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_subprocess 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_subprocess 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_ssl.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_ssl 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_ssl 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_ssl.cpython-37 2.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_ssl 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_ssl 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_scipy_signal.cpython-37 2.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_scipy_signal 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_scipy_signal 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_scipy_signal 2.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_scipy_signal 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_scipy_signal 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_responses.cpython-37 2.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_responses 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_responses 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_responses.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_responses 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_responses 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_re.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_re 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_re 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_re.cpython-37 2.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_re 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_re 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_pytest.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pytest 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pytest 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_pytest.cpython-37 2.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pytest 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pytest 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_pkg_resources 2.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pkg_resources 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pkg_resources 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_pkg_resources.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pkg_resources 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pkg_resources 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_numpy_random_mtrand.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_random_mtrand 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_random_mtrand 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_numpy_random_mtrand.cpython-37 2.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_random_mtrand 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_random_mtrand 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_numpy_ndarray.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_ndarray 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_ndarray 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_numpy_ndarray.cpython-37 2.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_ndarray 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_ndarray 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_numpy_core_umath 2.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_core_umath 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_core_umath 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_numpy_core_umath.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_core_umath 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_core_umath 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_numpy_core_numerictypes.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_core_numerictypes 2.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_core_numerictypes 2.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_http 2.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_http 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_http 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_http.cpython-37 2.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_http 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_http 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_curses.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_curses 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_curses 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_curses.cpython-37 2.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_curses 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_curses 3.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_collections 2.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_collections 4.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_collections 4.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_collections.cpython-37.pyc deleted in version3ascii and renamed to venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_collections 3.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_collections 3.py left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Then, when I run `git mergetool`, I get:

```
git mergetool
Merging:
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_collections 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_collections 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_curses 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_curses 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_http 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_http 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_core_numerictypes 2.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_core_umath 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_core_umath 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_ndarray 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_ndarray 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_random_mtrand 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_numpy_random_mtrand 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pkg_resources 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pkg_resources 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pytest 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_pytest 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_re 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_re 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_responses 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_responses 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_scipy_signal 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_scipy_signal 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_ssl 3.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_ssl 4.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_subprocess 3.py

Deleted merge conflict for 'venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/brain/brain_collections 3.py':
  {local}: created file
  {remote}: deleted
Use (c)reated or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort? a
Continue merging other unresolved paths [y/n]? n
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

I don't recall renaming or deleting any `venv/lib/*` files.

(This is part of a Heroku web app — i.e., the app is currently being run off of `master`. Not sure if that's relevant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that `.gitignore` content itself never has any direct effect on a merge.  That is because `git merge` merges the contents of *commits*, which are already committed and cannot be changed.  They have the files that they have.  No power on Earth, or anywhere else, can change them.  Your `git merge` is merging some existing commits, in preparation for making a new commit.

> I have run `git rm '*.pyc'` in both files ...

Do you mean "in both commits"?  "In both files" makes little sense here.

> I don't recall renaming or deleting any `venv/lib/*` files.

If `venv/lib` contained `*.pyc` files, and you ran the above `git rm`, you would remove those `*.pyc` files from both your work-tree and Git's index.  Once the files are out of Git's index, *then* the existing `*.pyc` entry in an existing `.gitignore` can take effect, preventing future `*.pyc` files from entering Git's index via your work-tree.  A subsequent commit would then lack those `*.pyc` files.

I'll just look at the first conflict here, and split up long lines for posting purposes only:

> ```
> CONFLICT (rename/delete):
> venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
> astroid/brain/__pycache__/brain_subprocess.cpython-37 2.pyc
> deleted in version3ascii and renamed to
> venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
> astroid/brain/brain_subprocess 3.py
> in HEAD. ...
> ```

All this really means is that:

- the *merge base* commit contains a file named `.../__pycache__/brain_subprocess.cpython-37 2.pyc`;
- the `version3ascii` commit *lacks* this file; and
- the `HEAD` version *also* lacks this file, but has a *new* file named `.../astroid/brain/brain_subprocess 3.py`

and the `HEAD` contents of that new name resemble the merge base contents under the old name, enough so that `git merge` decided that whoever made the changes between the merge base commit and the `HEAD` commit must have renamed (and perhaps also modified) the merge-base copy of the file.

It seems much more likely that the merge base commit has these `*.pyc` files *and* all these `venv/*` files, and that the `*.pyc` files are properly removed in both branch-tip commits (`version3ascii` branch tip, and current branch tip).  However, some `venv/*` files are present in `HEAD`, but probably not in `version3ascii` (otherwise Git probably would have detected a similar rename there).  It also seems likely that the `.py` file *isn't* a renamed-and-modified copy of the `.pyc` file and Git's similarity detector has merely mis-detected this as a rename.

There are numerous paths forward.  For instance:

- If no `venv/*` files should be in either branch-tip commit, you can just make two new branch-tip commits that lack those files.  Now Git won't find similar-looking files to claim as renames, that make Git believe things that aren't true.
- If you don't want to make new commits, you can abort this merge and re-run with an extended-argument (`-X` argument) that sets the rename threshold higher or turns off the rename detector entirely, e.g., `git merge -Xfind-renames=99` to limit it to 99% similar files, instead of 50% similar files.
- Or, you can simply adjust everything in Git's index manually.  The fact is, the merge has stopped with a merge conflict.  It is now your job to arrange to have the *correct* merge results.  These need not match any of the three input commits, although it's likely that the correct merge uses all three inputs in some way.  Since `git merge` *has come to a complete halt*, you now have *full control* over what will be in its index when you eventually run `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to finish the merge.  You can run `git rm -r .` to remove literally everything, construct all new files from whole cloth, and `git add`.

(Probably one of the other options is more useful than the nuke-and-pave one, and even if you do go for a nuke-and-pave—remove and re-create—you probably don't want to do it wholesale like this.)

Comment: I went down the `git merge -Xfind-renames=99 version3ascii` path, and it seemed to get me where I wanted to go, though I'm not sure I could explain back to you why. For example, I don't understand why the venv files would be in the master but not version3ascii, nor do I understand the relationship between the venv/* and the *.pyc files. (I went with the second method because I think I may need the venv in the master in the future.) Your forensic analysis was very impressive, and the commit-file distinction will likely be useful to me moving forward, insofar as I do move forward not another way

Comment: The `venv/*` files are those built by `virtualenv`. They include Python source files, which Python will turn into `.pyc` compiled files (or pyd or pyo files depending on options), in the same directory (Python 2) or the `__pycache__` subdirectory of the directory in which the `*.py` files are found (Python 3). Typically you'd prevent any such files from getting into any commit from the beginning of the project, in which case they'd not be in any commits. But once they're in *some* commit, well ... no commit can ever be *changed*, so now you're stuck.

Comment: It's usually wisest to clean them out, but you still have to remember that they will come back whenever you revisit any historical commit, and `git merge` itself finds some historical commit to act as the merge base. If the right historical commit is one that has the files, then one or both of the two commits that you're merging has, in effect, *deleted* the files. This problem fades away over time as new commits, including new merge bases, start to lack the files that they should omit, but it doesn't all get fixed at once.

Comment: Depending on your particular situation, too, you might have cases where you *do* want the `venv/` files. Here, you still almost certainly *don't* want the `*.pyc` files, though.